# Capistrano Error: '/usr/bin/env ruby : No such file or directory'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, capistrano, unicorn

When I try to restart **unicorn** using **Capistrano**:

```
$ cap production deploy:restart_unicorn
```

I got this error:

```
DEBUG [c65b4a92]  /usr/bin/env:
DEBUG [c65b4a92]  ruby
DEBUG [c65b4a92]  : No such file or directory
```

**My environment:**

- Mac OSX 10.9.2
- Capistrano Version: 3.2.1 (Rake Version: 10.3.1)
- rvm 1.25.25 (stable)
- ruby 2.1.2p95
- Rails 4.1.1
- Bundler 1.6.2

**My server environment:**

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)

**My config/deploy.rb:**

```
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'my_app'
set :repo_url,    'git@gitrepo.com:my_app.git'
set :deploy_to,   '/var/www/my_app'

set :linked_files, %w{.env}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache public/system}
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.1.2'

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart_unicorn do
    on roles :app, in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute 'service unicorn upgrade'
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart_unicorn
end
```

**My unicorn init script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
. /etc/environment

TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/var/www/my_app/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="$APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E $RAILS_ENV"
action="$1"
set -u

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

case $action in
restart)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  $CMD
  ;;
esac
```

**My Gemfile:**

```
# ...
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
# ...
```

**My Capfile:**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the problem just adding the **PATH** variable to my unicorn init script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
. /etc/environment

PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:$PATH
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rvm to select one of your rubies you might want to use [Capistrano's](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/) or [RVM's](https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3) gems as they will set up any other necessary ruby paths you missed.

And allow you to update ruby using rvm, as needed.